# Intellij cannot sync private repository

Tags: github, intellij-idea

I have recently imported a project from a private repository and a lot f the dependencies are not syncing. Everytime I run sync I get the error

```
git@github.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I have already imported the project using an access token and SSH. Still nothing works.

What should I do so that these dependencies can sync

Comment: IJ relies on the command line git. The message looks like invalid SSH  ley (or no key) is used. How does fetching from those repositories work on CLI?

Comment: I have actually configured an SSH key both on github and locally. I don't know how fetching would work on the CLI

Comment: Did you try cloning the repo from shell? Is it working?